# Не могу отсортировать массив строк по их длине (сортировка пузырьком)

Tags: java, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Для массива из int все работает корректно

```
public static void main(String[] args) {     
       String s;
       String[] str = new String[]{"this","is","a","test","of","i","string","sort"};
        for(int a=1;a<str.length;a++)
            for(int b = str.length-1;b>=a;b--)
                if(str[b-1].compareTo(str[b])<0){
                    s=str[b-1];
                    str[b-1]=str[b];
                    str[b]=s;
                }
        for (String i : str) System.out.println(i);

    }
```

Программа выводит:
a
i
is
of
sort
string
test
this

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку №1: ¿Где в этом коде сравнение по длине? Вопрос на засыпку №2: ¿Как может работать сортировка по длине для массива из int, если все элементы имеют одинаковую длину?

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою  тупость. Задачу я брал из книги, где было сказано изменить программу (сортировка пузырьком int массива), так чтобы она сортировала массив строк. И в ответе был приведён такой код.

Comment: ¿Так а зачем тогда выдумывать про сортировку по длине если в задании такого не было?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так

```
if(str[b-1].compareTo(str[b])<0)
```

выполняет сравнение строк по умолчанию ("по алфавиту"), а вам нужно по длине

```
if(str[b-1].length() < str[b].length())
```